# How to create dropdown component in ionic 3

Tags: extjs, ionic-framework, dynamic, components, dropdown

first let me say that I am newbie with ionic, I tried find my solution in Google, but now the information is mixed with ionic 1, ionic 2 and now "ionic 3".

I need do a dropdown menu which I call "create method" with parameters and this method draw menu with options.

I tested different methods, first try modify popups, then modals, but I can't solve my problem.

I need know the best form to do this, I think that I should make external component and use his methods to do what I want. I used Sencha Touch so far now, and I used this code to this:

```
    Ext.create("Amix.view.general.Menu",{
        options : options,
        callback : callback
    });

    Ext.define('Amix.view.general.Menu',{
        extend: 'Ext.panel',

        ...

        listeners: {
                
            initialize: function(){
              
               Ext.Viewport.add(this);
             
               ...
```

This is what I want:

[image]

Also, what is the best form to select item of the DOM? In sencha I used `Ext.getCmp()` or `Ext.select()`, `$()` on jQuery, or `document.queryselector` on JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

As per your screenshot, you need ionic Popover. For Ionic 2.x and 3.x there inbuilt component by ionic [Popover](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/popover/PopoverController/)

You can use this simply importing to your page

```
import { PopoverController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({})
class MyPage {
  constructor(public popoverCtrl: PopoverController) {}

  presentPopover(myEvent) {
    let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create(PopoverPage);
    popover.present({
      ev: myEvent
    });
  }
}
```

See demo [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/popover/PopoverController/)

Comment: Ty for answer, I first did with Popover but my problem is that I need that the menu appear since top, and I tried modifie style but ionic 2 creates style automatically and I can't modify animation

Comment: What style you can't update ? there you can use page `scss` for a page css, `app.scss` for global css update.

Comment: there ionic conference app having popover example for about page. https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-conference-app/tree/master/src/pages

Comment: I know I change style with app.scss, but I want change z-Index because menu appears behind header toolbar, and I want change top too to do animation, and ionic 3 put default style.

Thx again

Comment: If i do with popover this happens:

https://ibb.co/gjcdpa

When I animate popover, it goes over header :(

Comment: i am not good much with css, try `position:relative`  if help.